# column vector dot product with transpose

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have an orthonormal base, $B = \{v_1, v_2, \ldots v_n\}$ for space $\mathbb R^n$.

Assuming $v_1$ is a row vector, what is $v_i^t \cdot v_i$ ?

Is it a scalar, or is it an $n\times n$ matrix with a 1 in the [ ]$_{i,i}$ spot?

Answer (score 1):

$v_i^t$ is of size $n\times 1$ since it is a column, and $v_j$ is of size $1\times n$ since it is a row.

Therefore $v_i^t \cdot v_i$ is of size $n \times n$.

Assuming $v=(v_1,...,v_n)$, $w=(w_1,...,w_n)$, $(v^t\cdot w)_{ij}=v_iw_j$.

Comment: How do you calculate it?

Comment: @Etai: added it to my comment.